# Matplotlib & eval program

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, eval

I need to write a program,using matplotlib,which draw a graph of function that i write in **console!!!!**
I don't know how to  work with trigonometric functions such as:cos,sin,tg,ctg,ect.
This what i have:

```
import math
from numpy import linspace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print("input a:")
a = float(input())
print("input b:")
b = float(input())
x = linspace(a, b, 1001)

formula = input()

y = eval(formula,{'sin(x)': math.sin(float(x))})

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel(u'x')
plt.ylabel(u'y')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Plt.plot  takes in two lists(x,y) as input and plot them. U can do something like x is a range of values and y is f(x)

Input()- returns a string

U can do a switch case if there are fixed number of cases(functions).

Eval() is used for evaluating a expression or converting data type etc. Literal eval is recommended  over eval

Comment: I tried something like that but it didn't work properly :(

Comment: Is there an error? Or what's happening?

Comment: Ok,can u tell me how to do this with eval?

Comment: Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58474882/how-to-use-sinx-and-cosx-functions-with-eval). Use numpy instead of math.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Okay but numpy can't calculate sin^2(x) or sin(x^2)

Comment: No, because `eval` needs valid python input, and `^` is not valid python.

Comment: I know but the problem was in another thing: i tried to write sin^2(x) but it was not correct and now i found that i need to write sin(x)^2,but thanks a lot for your help:)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you just want to draw the graph of `sin(x)`, then you don't need `eval()`.